# Hide fragment identifiers from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide the fragment identifiers from the url after clicking of div at same page.

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    alert(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
 });

});
```

the url is something like this `http://www.example.com#about` but i want to be like this `http://www.example.com`

I tried of changing the `$target.offset` and also `return false;` at the end of click function but they did not work.

Comment: The only real way to do that is to change the href in the anchors to not use hashes.

Comment: Please don't confuse [hashtags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtag) with [fragment identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: adeneo sorry i am not getting you

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting any of you :) Isn't this just `location.hash = ''`?

Comment: You're explicitly setting the fragment identifier here: `window.location.hash = target;` - just remove this line, or use `window.location.hash = ''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing your animation completion callback.
Since you do `preventDefault()` I am pretty sure you wouldn't get hash anymore if you remove it.

If this does not work, replace it with `window.location.hash = ''`.

Comment: Thank you andrey works fine by replacing window.location.hash=''

Comment: @musthafa If an answer worked and you feel it is correct you can accept it. I notice you haven't accepted any answers yet.

Comment: @musthafa For reference, "upvoting" a comment does not confer any reputation to the user who made it - simply marking it as *"useful"* to any other users browsing the question (and makes it more likely the comment will not be hidden when the comment count rises and some start to be hidden by default). Accepting (the green tick) and/or upvoting an answer helps future users with the same problem immediately see that the answer helped you/solved the problem, and rewards users who take time to answer. It also makes it more likely your future questions will be answered - **and** gives you rep.

Comment: Yaaa @pwdst i tried to give upvote but it shows me that i need of 15 reputations i cant able to do that, whether i can post it as answer